# AS3: Local 2D to Global 3D?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d

So, since 3D layers got introduced, AS3 supports the following functions:

`local3DtoGlobal(point3D:Vector3D):Point`

and

`globalToLocal3D(point:Point):Vector3D`

the first one transforming the point inside of a 3D transformed layer to global 2D stage coordinates and the second one returning the local coordinates of a 2D stage location projected onto a 3D plane (the z coordinate of the Vector3D will be 0).

What i need however is something like

`local2DToGlobal3D(point:Point):Vector3D`

that takes 2D local coordinates (within the 3D transformed layer) and returns a Vector3D that represents the position in global 3D space.

example:

```
//_foo3D:MovieClip is a MovieClip with a 3D rotation applied to it, child of the stage
//_bar:MovieClip is some test MovieClip, child of the stage
function asdf(){
    var p:Point = new Point(50,50);
    _foo3D.graphics.beginFill(0,1);
    _foo3D.graphics.drawCircle(p.x, p.y, 50);
    _foo3D.graphics.endFill();

    var p3D:Vector3D = _foo3D.FUNCTIONINEED(p);
    _bar.x = p3D.x;
    _bar.y = p3D.y;
    _bar.z = p3D.z;

//the movieClip _bar should now optically lie over the circle drawn within _foo3D
}
```

how to do this? hope the problem is clear. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://blog.zupko.info/?p=143).  Does that help?  Basically you need to unproject the 2D coordinates into your 3D space.  You then get a vector that is pointing in the direction of your mouse in 3D world.  I normally normalize this vector (make it length 1) and then form that you can check difference z distances and find out what the corresponding x and y coordinates of the mouse are at that z position.  You can use this information to check for an intersection with various objects you have in 3D space.

For more information about unprojecting take a look at [this](http://myweb.lmu.edu/dondi/share/cg/unproject-explained.pdf) which will help explain some of the theory (keep in mind whatever function they are talking about you would need to write... I don't know of one for flash as3... you might want to try google search for it).